# How can I play all animations clips from animator controller one by one?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The main goal is to play all the animations in the List one by one to play the first one to wait for it to finish playing and then start the next one.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayAnimations : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator animator;

    private List<AnimationClip> clips = new List<AnimationClip>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        foreach (AnimationClip ac in animator.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips)
        {
            StartCoroutine(PlayAll(ac.name, ac.length));
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator PlayAll(string stateName, float length)
    {
        animator.Play(stateName);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(length);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

But it's playing only one animation clip and there are two in the animator controller. Why ?

It's playing only the second one the first one that have the StateMachine Default State is not playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting all Coroutines for different states/animations at the "same" time (at least in the same frame) so they all run `animator.Play` "concurrently".

So in the first frame both Coroutines set the according state, first for the first animation, than for the second animation, etc.

=> you only have the last one in the list actually running because it is the only one that doesn't get "overruled" by a following `animator.Play` call.

Instead move your for-loop to the Coroutine:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(PlayAll());
}

public IEnumerator PlayAll()
{
    foreach (AnimationClip ac in animator.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips)
    {
        animator.Play(ac.name);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(ac.length);
    }
}
```

---

However actually the whole idea of the StateMachine is having transitions .. so you could simply connect both states/animations with a transition that has

- `UseExitTime` enabled
- `ExitTime = 1`
- `Duration` (of the transition or fading if you want so) `0`

than it automatically goes to the next animation after the first one finished. (You now also could even loop them by simply having a transition back to the first state.)

So you actually wouldn't need any script for this at all.

---

Otherwise you could also use the [Animation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.html) component without states, transitions, layers and the controller.

Code would only be slightly different:

```
// Assuming here this script is attached to the same object as the Animation component
// Ofcourse you can also keep it public and reference the component yourself
private Animation animation;

public List<AnimationClip> clips = new List<AnimationClip>();

private void Awake()
{
    animation = GetComponent<Animation>();
}

private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(PlayAll());
}

private IEnumerator PlayAll()
{
    foreach(var clip in clips)
    {
        animation.Play(clip.name);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(clip.length);
    }
}
```

The `Animation` component is marked as legacy but this might change because of its simplicity in e.g. your use case.

Comment: Is there a way to add a transition/s between animations(states) by script ? For example in this case in the editor in the animator controller I have 12 states could be 30 or more and adding transition between each state/s can take a long time.

Comment: Yes you actually can ( [reference](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-add-and-delete-transitions-in-script.293462/)) but it's a bit complicated and only available in the editor so you have to make sure it is not built into the final app